# Opening images in Win 7 not working anymore - " COM surrogate has stopped working " error

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, images, windows-photo-viewer

I have Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit, with all updates installed. Suddenly, from some moment on today I can no longer open images with Windows Photo Viewer. I get " COM surrogate has stopped working " error if I try to open an image file. But I can see the preview of the image in the Explorer, as well as thumbnail. I can also open images with Paint. After the problem has started I have been sending some images through Skype. There I can double-click the icon and image opens fine in Windows Photo Viewer. I can also "scroll" and other images that are in same directory are being shown.

As a side note, I have just noticed that if I right click the Computer icon and choose properties, I get " Windows Explorer has stopped working " error. Windows Explorer then restarts itself. I don't get this problem for right clicking and opening properties for other files or folders. I suppose it is correlated to the image problem.

How can I solve this issue and continue using Windows Photo Viewer normally ?

**EDIT :**

There seems to have been [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/564795/windows-photo-viewer-terminating-with-com-surrogate-error) regarding this issue here. But for that particular case, updating drivers worked. I have Nvidia 9500 GT, and Nvidia GeForce Experience program tells my drivers are up to date - even after clicking the "Check for updates" button.

Comment: crate dump of the DLLhost.exe and share it : https://www.dropbox.com/s/2kmalsgys8koz6o/WER_dllhost.exe.reg . The reg generates a dump in C:\localdumps, so zip the file, upload the zip to a cloud service and post a link here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your drivers might be corrupt. I would download the latest drivers and reinstall. Uninstall current drivers first.

Here is a link to current drivers for the 9500 GT series and Windows 7 64 bit.

[335.23 - WHQL](http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/73780)

[337.50 - BETA](http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/74636)

If that doesn't work you can try to see if any system files are corrupt. Hit the start button then type in `CMD`. Right click and select `Run as Administrator` in the command prompt type in `SFC /SCANNOW` If your windows is pirated this command will break the crack. Also if you have made any system changes like changed notepad to something different it will revert it back.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I will follow your instructions and see if it works. I have a genuine OS version, but I hope I will solve the issue before I would have to use the SFC /SCANNOW resort.